# Load second XML layout when click a button

Tags: android

How do I view a second xml layout  beside the main layout with  click button listener. And to get some variable in that layout? Sory this beginner question, but I cannot find the similar question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put another layout from other XML inside the one you already have, you could use **LayoutInflater** too.

```
// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
// Get the view
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout, null);
```

[Link of documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

[]'s

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show another layout beside the current one, you should use Fragments.
See the links below to some explanation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Inflate the "second" layout (`second_layout.xml`):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Get the View:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, null);
```

Get an element inside the `second_layout.xml`, for example if you have a TextView with  `android:id="@+id/txtview_description"`:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_description);
```